# align primary menu items to the right

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment

I have a website and I am trying to align all its menu items in primary nav bar to the right. Below is the image of results that I want to achieve

[image]

I have tried it with CSS but could not able find the right technique. The website name is [obscot.com](http://obscot.com) Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  your  site  add  this  css  bottom  of  the  css  file

```
#masthead .main-navigation {

    right: 60px;
    text-align: right;

 }
```

Comment: Hey, how'd you do it ? I mean I know some CSS coding I am trying to achieve this result since 2 days. I am using inspect element method, how have you done it ?

Comment: please share with me I want to understand it better

Comment: i  used  firebug  and  tried  to find  out  the  css  and  i saw  that in 
 .main-navigation  class you have  used  right  attribute  and  the  attribute  value  is  300.  i  just  chnge  the  value  using firebug  and  its show   perfect if  i  use  60.

Comment: oh ! okay. I did not know about the `right` property in CSS. Now I got it

Answer (score 0):

If  you are  using  bootstrap  then  just  add  this  class

```
navbar-right
```

sample  example Here: -

```
   class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"
```

If  you want to write  row  CSS then  use  this.

```
.navbar li{

 float:right;
 display:inline;

}
```

Comment: I am using wordpress

Comment: For your site add this css bottom of the css file                                         #masthead .main-navigation {

    right: 60px;
    text-align: right;

 }